# What do we lose in Projective Spaces?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

We can think of the Complex Numbers as an extension of the Real Numbers, similarly we can think of the Projective Plane naturally as a nice extension of the Euclidean Plane. But, when we go from real to complex numbers we lose some structure, for example total ordering, we $\textit{can't}$ ask about ordering anymore.

$\textbf{Question:}$ What do we lose by working in the Projective Plane? In other words, what "euclidean" questions don't make sense in the projective context?

Comment: Well, you lose the fact that two distinct parallel lines never cross

Comment: @AlexH. No, you _gain_ the fact that all distinct lines now intersect! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You lose the vector space structure and even the affine structure and even the additive group structure when you go from $\mathbb C$ to $\mathbb P^1_\mathbb C$.
 More concretely,  given two points in  $\mathbb P^1_\mathbb C$ it doesn't make sense to talk of their difference as a vector.
The general context  is that $\mathbb C$ has both algebraic and geometric features while $\mathbb  P^1_\mathbb C$ has no algebraic structure whatsoever but has many geometric structures:

As a topological space, manifold, Riemannian manifold, Riemann surface [ not  synonymous at all with the former !], conformal space, algebraic curve,...

Comment: I'm very naive of this subject so I apologize if this is stupid but is "...$\mathbb  P^1_\mathbb C$ has no algebraic structure whatsoever..." to be taken literally? It's not even closed under some operator, i.e magma?

Comment: Dear @John, of course you can  artificially impose an algebraic structure on $\mathbb P^1_\mathbb C$, as you can on any set!, but as far as know no interesting one.

Comment: @John Smith I guess the operative thing is that there is no algebraic statute on the projective line which plays nicely with the underlying structure of the variety. In other words, the projective line cannot be made into a group variety, like the affine line can.

Answer (score 3):

Lost: the metric structure: distances, angles, areas. Conserved: incidences. See http://www.nct.anth.org.uk/basics.htm.

Comment: There is a perfectly valid metric structure on projective space: the [Fubini-Study metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%E2%80%93Study_metric) .

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: of course you are right. But perhaps what Martín-Blas is saying is that the usual metric on Euclidean space does not _extend_ to a metric on projective space.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh, right